# how to submit form using button in cs cart

Tags: cs-cart

```
<div class="ty-company-fields">
    <div class="apply_for_vendor_account">
        <h1 class="tygh-top-panel ty-dropdown-box__title ty-mainbox-simple-title ty-mainbox-simple-container clearfix ty-homepage-vendors">Calculator</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" name="calculator" id="calculator">
            <div class="ty-control-group">
                <label for="contact_form" class="ty-control-group__title cm-required ty-input-text cm-focus" >Please Enter First Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="cal[value1]" id="contact_form" size="32" value="{$cal.value1}" class="ty-input-text cm-focus ty-control-group_title cm-required" />
            </div>    

            <div class="ty-control-group">
                <label for="contact_form_number" class="ty-control-group__title cm-required">Please Enter Second Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="cal[value2]" id="contact_form_number" class="ty-input-text cm-focus ty-control-group_title cm-required" size="32" value="{$cal.value2}"  />
            </div> 
            {if $result } 
            <p>The Result is: {$result}</p>
            {/if}
            <div class="buttons-container">
             {include file="buttons/button.tpl" but_text=__("submit") but_name="dispatch[calculator2.add]" but_id="contact" but_meta="ty-btn__primary" value = "+" data-ca-target-form="calculator" data-ca-dispatch="dispatch[calculator.calculator]"}


             {include file="buttons/button.tpl" but_text=__("submit") but_name="dispatch[calculator.add]" but_id="contact" but_meta="ty-btn__primary" value = "+"}
             {include file="buttons/button.tpl" but_text=__("submit") but_name="dispatch[calculator.add]" but_id="contact" but_meta="ty-btn__primary" value = "+"}
             {include file="buttons/button.tpl" but_text=__("submit") but_name="dispatch[calculator.add]" but_id="contact" but_meta="ty-btn__primary" value = "+"}

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the normal form and normal submit button, Normal way is also works fine in cs cart.

In this case, when you press the button the whole values are post to controller **calculator.add** and take the actions.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **form tag in action attribute**, you need this:

```
<form action="{""|fn_url}" method="post" name="calculator" id="calculator">
...
</form>
```

In the first parameter you could also insert a specific `dispatch` value, for example `calculator.manage` if you want to navigate to specific page of yours or leave it empty.

Moreover, inside your tpl file add this at the bottom (and inside capture smarty tag):

```
{capture name="buttons"}
    {include file="buttons/save.tpl" but_name="dispatch[calculator.manage]" but_role="submit-link" but_target_form="calculator"}
{/capture}
```

this capture smarty tag, will add the general **Save button** of cs-cart, at the right top corner.

Now, you probably have a controller file named `calculator.php` which also contain code like that:

```
if($mode == "manage") {
  //your code here
}
```